# Is writing to an array of floats from 2 different threads at two different indexes safe?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
float myfloats[2];

// thread A:
myFloats[0] = 1.0;

// thread B:
myFloats[1] = 1.0;
```

Assuming that thread A will always access index 0, thread B index 1.  Is this safe or can the array get corrupted?

Comment: I think it should be: you're just writing to two different memory locations that happen to lie close to eachother.

Comment: @godel9: I wouldn't call that a dup. The situation described there is much more complexe than an array of (properly aligned) floats. Doesn't mention C either, and C11 introduced a memory model that takes threading into account. I believe the above is safe in C11, but not certain.

Comment: Threading is outside of the scope of the C standard. You need to refer to the document that defines threading in your environment (OS/hardware/implementation of C). In many cases that would be either POSIX or Windows API.

Comment: Whether it is safe is unprovable.  That it is a [really dumb thing to do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) is more obvious.

Comment: @HansPassant - Cool thanks. If you were to expand on this comment, would you say that its dumb because it would lead to serious performance penalties?  The reason being that the nearby memory is being shared across threads?  (I didn't totally understand the wiki page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C11 n1570 draft standard appears to assert this is *safe*, but I assert that it is *unwise*.

---

I base my argument on the fact that the elements of an array cannot overlap in memory, and on the following clauses of the C11 draft standard.

> #### 5.1.2.4 *Multi-threaded executions and data races*
>
> 4. Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.
>
> 25. The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.
>
> 27. NOTE 13 Compiler transformations that introduce assignments to a potentially shared memory location that would not be modified by the abstract machine are generally precluded by this standard, since such an assignment might overwrite another assignment by a different thread in cases in which an abstract machine execution would not have encountered a data race. This includes implementations of data member assignment that overwrite adjacent members in separate memory locations. We also generally preclude reordering of atomic loads in cases in which the atomics in question may alias, since this may violate the "visible sequence" rules.
>
> 28. NOTE 14 Transformations that introduce a speculative read of a potentially shared memory location may not preserve the semantics of the program as defined in this standard, since they potentially introduce a data race. However, they are typically valid in the context of an optimizing compiler that targets a specific machine with well-defined semantics for data races. They would be invalid for a hypothetical machine that is not tolerant of races or provides hardware race detection.

We learn here that it is UB for two threads to perform conflicting actions on the same memory location, but that the compiler is "generally precluded" from introducing assignments to "potentially shared" memory locations that the abstract machine would not have performed.

You assert that your threads only access (read and write) the elements at their own specific index. Since there is no question that they don't access the same memory location, it therefore appears to me that what you are doing is safe, provided you meet all other constraints, such as proper alignment of your `float` variables.

---

However, I query the **wisdom** of doing as you propose. Since these two memory locations are contiguous, you will likely experience a severe *false sharing* problem. This is because CPUs generally cache memory in "lines" of around 32 or 64 contiguous bytes, and communicate cache status using the MESI protocol.

If a thread running on one core performs a write *anywhere* within this cacheline, then all copies of the cacheline and everything contained in it found in *other* cores are **invalidated**, usually leading to threads on those other cores needing to reread their updated copies from main memory. This is several times slower than accesses from cache.

*True sharing* occurs if the threads concerned were all accessing the same part of the cacheline, because this invalidation was then justified to prevent the communicating threads from using stale data.

On the other hand, *false sharing* occurs if the threads were all accessing different parts of the same cacheline. In this case, invalidation was not necessary, but the hardware did it anyways because of the proximity of the accesses to each other, penalizing all of them.

Comment: Thanks - I liked your expiation on true / false sharing.  It made much more sense than the wiki article on the same topic :)

Comment: Hmm, can you explain what you mean by `proper alignment of float vairables`? Or point to a good resource explaining as such?

Comment: @Gnuey Generally, computer architectures are designed so that it is fastest and easiest to load _naturally-aligned_ data from memory. For instance, a `float` is 4 bytes, so the address at which a float is found should preferably be evenly divisible by 4 (its _natural alignment is 4_). Computer architectures differ in how well they tolerate misaligned accesses; They may allow it at no penalty, some penalty or not at all, and they may or may not provide special instructions for misaligned accesses.